# High CPU Usage and Limit exceeds issue

Tags: wordpress, cpu-usage, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I have a WordPress site hosted with SiteGorund on their [GoGeek](https://www.siteground.com/shared-hosting-features.htm) plan. Its CPU usage limit exceeds every time and site closes for hours every time.

We are using [The7](https://themeforest.net/item/the7-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/5556590)  theme so PHP code is almost optimized. We also created child theme and tried to use as less plugin as we could.

We also optimized site so its page speed is `90 plus`. Why the CPU usage limit exceeds is the point we require help with.

We have contacted SiteGround, but they are saying *you require to optimze your PHP code*, but its alredy optimzed. Still every time CPU usage limit exceeds, which is headache for us.

Following is the list of the plugins we are using:

1. Accelerated Mobile Pages
2. Async JavaScript
3. Autoptimize
4. Duplicate Page And Post
   5 Elfsight YouTube Gallery CC
5. Gravity Forms
6. Heartbeat Control
7. OneSignal Push Notifications
8. Really Simple SSL
9. Redirection
10. SG Optimizer
11. Swift Performance Lite
12. Templatera
13. The7 Elements
14. The7 LayerSlider WP
15. The7 Slider Revolution
16. The7 Ultimate Addons for WPBakery Page Builder
17. The7 WPBakery Page Builder
18. Unlimited Addons for WPBakery Page Builder
19. VC Particles Background
20. WP Disable
21. WP User Avatar
22. Yoast SEO

We also tried fixes for everything like leverage browser caching, Gzip compression etc. Now page speed looks great, but the only issue is high CPU usage.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: These plugins seems to be redundant: 1. Async JavaScript, 2. Autoptimize, 3. SG Optimizer,4. Swift Performance Lite. If you are on SG's GoGeek plan, then SG Optimizer or Swift Performance Lite is enough for cache.

Comment: Your page is overloaded by plugins that are similar to each other (Yoast SEO and SG Optimizer). Try to delete some extensions ale take a look if the cpu usage has been reduced.

Comment: @KashifRafique every plugin is useful for page speed though some are similar but every plugin is doing their task to optimize speed so i don't think this could be the issue.

Comment: As you are on GoGeek plan, you can spin a staging site with a click. Try to disable/remove the redundant plugins on the staging site, run the tests and see the CPU load. In that way you can compare both sites side by side.

Answer (score 0):

What they said drop all the other speed plugins and just use SG optimizer.

Gravity Forms can be a bit of a resource hog.

The other option is you can try sp super cache. I belive that is a page level caching plugin so it will help with CPUtime. But you'd have to drop sg optimizer I think.